# limit login attempts using applicationlistener spring security 4 annotation based

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have used application listener foe limiting login attempts but not able to get where to register this application listener as my project is full annotation based with no `xml`

**Athentication Listener**

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationListener implements ApplicationListener <AbstractAuthenticationEvent>
{

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent appEvent)
    {
        System.out.println("got in authentication here");        
        if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent)
      {
          AuthenticationSuccessEvent event = (AuthenticationSuccessEvent) appEvent;
          // add code here to handle successful login event
          System.out.println("THERE WAS A SUCCESSFUL LOGIN");
      }

      if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent)
      {
          AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent event = (AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent) appEvent;

          // add code here to handle unsuccessful login event
          // for example, counting the number of login failure attempts and storing it in db
          // this count can be used to lock or disable any user account as per business requirements
          System.out.println("THERE WAS A UNSUCCESSFUL LOGIN");
      }
    }
}
```

**SpringSecurity**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//  @Autowired
//  @Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
//  static AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
//
//  @Autowired
//  public static void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
//  }

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
try{
    System.out.println("----TOP--------Http Security");
    http
    //.httpBasic()
    //.and()
    //.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER)
    //.and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/employees").access("hasRole('ROLE_idAdmin') or hasRole('ROLE_dAdmin')")
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/employees/?*").access("hasRole('ROLE_technician') or hasRole('ROLE_DADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_IDADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_WADMIN')")
    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/employees").access("hasRole('ROLE_IDADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DADMIN')")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/employees").access("hasRole('ROLE_IDADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_DRADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_WADMIN')")
    //.antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/employees").access("hasRole('ROLE_IDADMIN')")
    //.antMatchers("/main").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
    //.antMatchers("/confidential/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPERADMIN')")
//  .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/index.jsp")

//  .and()
//    .httpBasic();
    //.and()
    //.logout()
        //.permitAll();
    ;
        System.out.println("----Bottom--------Http Security");
    //.logout();

//getConnection();
    //http.addFilterAfter(new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
     http.csrf().disable();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("http Security error");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

@Configuration
protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
        GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

//  @Autowired
//  //@Qualifier("authenticationProvider")
//  static AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    //@Autowired//custom addition
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("1111111111111111Authentication Manager Got here1111111");


        auth
        .ldapAuthentication()
        .userSearchFilter("uid={0}")
        .userSearchBase("ou=users")
        .groupSearchFilter("uniqueMember={0}")
        .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
        .groupRoleAttribute("cn")
        .rolePrefix("ROLE_")
        .contextSource(getLdapContextSource());

        //auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
        System.out.println("Authentication Manager Got here");
    }
    private LdapContextSource getLdapContextSource() throws Exception {
        LdapContextSource cs = new LdapContextSource();
        cs.setUrl("ldap://localhost:1389/");
        cs.setBase("o=id workshop");
        cs.setUserDn("uid=admin,ou=system");
        cs.setPassword("secret");
        cs.afterPropertiesSet();
        return cs;
    }
    }
}
```

**AppInitializer**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
//import org.krams.tutorial.controller.Equivalentwebxml;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

import com.authenticationattempt.AuthenticationListener;

public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { EquivalentServlet.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }
```

**EquivalentServlet**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.security.SpringSecurity;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.controller" })
@Import(value = { SpringSecurity.class })
//@Import(value = { AuthenticationListener.class})
public class EquivalentServlet {
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        //viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }



}
```

Comment: You already have `@Component` on there so if you specified the correct base package in `@ComponentScan` you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for the reply
I supplied the correct base package name in '@ComponentScan' but its still not working
do i need to add something in my springsecurity.java ??

Comment: No however it looks like you haven't even setup spring security correctly (does that even work?). You seem to be missing a filter or a class that extends `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer` to register the filter.